# Post-Condition Violation with Feature in Eiffel

Tags: eiffel

This is part of the class. This class is called BAG[G -> {HASHABLE, COMPARABLE}]
it inherits from ADT_BAG which has deferred features such as count, extend, remove, remove_all, add_all... more, and domain to be re-implemented.

domain returns ARRAY[G] which is a sorted array list of G

i always get Post-condition violation "value_semantics" which is something to do with object comparison but I checked and there is no code for object comparison which is very weird.

I tried to remake the code for domain feature several times and it ALWAYS ends up with a post-condition violation or a fail.

When I check the debugger the array "a" that is returned from domain always has count 0 but this does not make sense because i move keys from table to "a" but count is still 0.

Maybe I am transferring the keys wrong to the array?

code:

```
count: INTEGER
        -- cardinality of the domain
    do
        result := domain.count -- has to be domain.count because loop invariant: consistent: count = domain.count
    end


domain: ARRAY[G]
        -- sorted domain of bag
    local
        tmp: G
        a: ARRAY[G]

    do
        create a.make_empty

        across 1 |..| (a.count) as i  -- MOVING keys from table to array
          loop
                across table as t
                  loop
                       if not a.has (t.key) then
                            a.enter (t.key, i.item)
                            i.forth
                       end
                  end

           end

        across 1 |..| (a.count-1) as i  -- SORTING
          loop
                if a[i.item] > a[i.item+1] then
                    tmp := a[i.item]
                    a[i.item] := a[i.item+1]
                    a[i.item+1] := tmp
                end

           end

    Result := a

    ensure then
        value_semantics: Result.object_comparison -- VIOLATION THROWN HERE
        correct_items: across 1 |..| Result.count as j all
            has(Result[j.item]) end
        sorted: across 1 |..| (Result.count-1) as j all
            Result[j.item] <= Result[j.item+1] end
    end
```

test code:

```
     t3: BOOLEAN
    local
        sorted_domain: ARRAY[STRING]
    do
        comment("t3:test sorted domain")
        sorted_domain := <<"bolts", "hammers", "nuts">>
        sorted_domain.compare_objects
        Result := bag2.domain ~ sorted_domain -- fails here
        check Result end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop `across 1 |..| (a.count) as i` is not going to make a single iteration because `a` is empty (has no elements) at the beginning. Indeed, it has been just created with `create a.make_empty`.

Also, because keys in the table are unique it is useless to check whether a key has been added to the resulting array: the test `not a.has (t.key)` will always succeed.

Therefore the first loop should go over keys of a table and add them into the resulting array. The feature `{ARRAY}.force` may be of interest in this case. The addition of the new elements should not make any "holes" in the array though. One way to achieve this is to add a new element right after the current upper bound of the array.

The sorting loop is also incorrect. Here the situation is reversed compared to the previous one: sorting cannot be done in a single loop, at least two nested loops are required. The template seems to be using *Insertion sort*, its algorithm can be found [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

**EDIT:** the original answer referred to `{ARRAY}.extend` instead of `{ARRAY}.force`. Unfortunately `{ARRAY}.extend` is not generally available, but `a.extend (x)` would have the same effect as `a.force (x, a.upper + 1)`.